# jquery target ul li but exclude ul child li

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have an ul list of li items, including a child ul.
I'm trying to target only the first li and exclude childrens li.

here's my list :

```
<li class="sf-field-taxonomy">

    <ul>

        <li class="sf-level-0">

            <input id="sf-input">
            <label>aaaa</label>

            <ul class="children">

                <li class="sf-level-1">

                    <input id="sf-input">
                    <label>bbbb</label>

                </li>

                <li class="sf-level-1">

                    <input id="sf-input">
                    <label>cccc</label>

                </li>

                <li class="sf-level-1">

                    <input id="sf-input">
                    <label>dddd</label>

                </li>

                <li class="sf-level-1">

                    <input id="sf-input">
                    <label>eeee</label>

                </li>

            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>

</li>
```

I'm able to target only children li by using this code :

```
$(".sf-field-taxonomy li:not(:has(ul))").click(function(){

    console_log("children");

});
```

but I can't access the fist li only (and exclude children li), here's what I've tried :

```
$(".sf-field-taxonomy ul li").not(".children li").click(function(){

    console_log("parent");

});
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, can anybody help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a click in a child element bubbles up to the parent. You need to write a click handler for the child that prevents bubbling.

```js
$(".sf-field-taxonomy > ul > li").click(function() {
  console.log("Parent");
});
$(".children").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sf-field-taxonomy">
  <ul>
    <li class="sf-level-0">
      <input id="sf-input">
      <label>aaaa</label>
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="sf-level-1">
          <input id="sf-input">
          <label>bbbb</label>
        </li>
        <li class="sf-level-1">
          <input id="sf-input">
         <label>cccc</label>
        </li>
        <li class="sf-level-1">
          <input id="sf-input">
          <label>dddd</label>
        </li>
        <li class="sf-level-1">
          <input id="sf-input">
          <label>eeee</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```